# Javascript Regex to ignore first character in match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to ignore a '.' at the start of my regular expression, and have been somewhat stumped.

My current regex is:

```
(?::)(\d{3})
```

Which matches the following:

[image: Image here]

When I try to ignore the '.' with the following regex:

```
[^.](?::)(\d{3})
```

I get this:

[image: Picture here]

As it seems to be adding the extra character like '<', which is unwanted.

How do I go about to ignore that extra character in front of the ':' ?

Comment: Regex101 here: http://regex101.com/r/cE0wH4/1

Comment: @hwnd may i know the reason?

Comment: `:` should be included.

Comment: You're going through a lot of effort to ignore a character. The way I ignore characters is I don't put it in the regex.

Comment: I would say the answer is you have to match the character before the colon, no matter what it is, then check if it matched a dot `.` or not. May require some extra code.

Comment: `[^.]` will match any character that is not a period, which is why you're getting the `<`.  Regex is best for matching, and not ignoring.  What is it you are trying to accomplish with this regex that you need to ignore the period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this alternation based regex:

```
\.:\d{3}|:(\d{3})
```

And grab captured group #1 for your matches.

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cE0wH4/4)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works great! (especially without the lookahead).

Answer (score 1):

Just use a lookahead to match the strings in this `:\d{3}` format preceded by any  but not of dot.

```
(?=[^.](:(\d{3})))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cE0wH4/5)

Group 1 contains the string with `:`, and the group 2 contains only the digits.

Comment: What if input is `:999 Test .:123 This`

Comment: @anubhava he don't want to capture the string `:\d{3}` which is preceeded by a dot.

Comment: The not `.` will bump the position past it and it will match with the dot behind it.

Comment: Right I know. But in the input: `:999 Test .:123 foo.`, it should capture `999` also.

Comment: yep, it is not preceded by a dot.

Comment: So you see the problem with this approach. Unfortunately JS doesn't have lookbehind to solve it easily.

Comment: This might work, if the engine does bump along, and since the `:\d{3}` is inflexible. The only problem is it requires a char before the `:`.

Comment: Would changing the regex to this help? `(?=[^.])(:(\d{3}))`

Comment: @SurferL - No that wouldn't help. That's what I thought it originally was. This is a fallacy in the use of look-aheads. For this string `.:123` if the position is between `.` and `:` it see's the `:` is not a dot from the lookahead, then proceeds to match `:123` with the dot behind it.